# Как перевести число из одного диапазона в другой?

Tags: javascript, математика

Помогите на JS составить формулу.

Нужно получить значение в пикселях, по значение в позиции.

Нужна просто математическая формула, не важно в каком виде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте вспомнить математику и составить формулу на листочке, она не так сложна

Comment: @Kromster, знаю что она не сложная, но не получается ее сделать, наверное математика не мое

Comment: `400 * (2.4 - 1.4) / (2.6 - 1.4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот псевдокод, `old` - старое значение, `converted` - новое:

```
old_range = old_max - old_min  
new_range = new_max - new_min  
converted = (((old - old_min) * new_range) / old_range) + new_min
```

Если вам надо конкретно из `[1.4...; 2.6...]` перевести в `[0; 400]`, то ответ `333.11798220627696` (если я правильно все цифры переписал :) ).

Тест на питоне:

```
old_min, old_max = 5, 10
new_min, new_max = 15, 20
old = 7
    
old_range = old_max - old_min  
new_range = new_max - new_min  
converted = ((old - old_min) * new_range / old_range) + new_min
    
print(converted)
```

Выводит `17`

Comment: new_max - new_min это получается 400 - 0, из моего примера ?

Comment: @SergeyMironov я не понимаю, что у вас на картинке в примере :) `old_min, old_max` это минимальное и максимальное значение первого диапазона (из которого переводим), а `new_min, new_max` - соответственно, второго (туда, куда переводим) тут

Comment: @SergeyMironov если вам надо из `[1.4...; 2.6...]` перевести в `[0; 400]`, то да. Тогда ответ `333.11798220627696` (если я правильно все цифры переписал :) )