# Как рассчитать размер между двумя размерами внутри блока и нарисовать линию с нужным отступом?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Нужно верно расположить `marked`

```js
let start = 20; // Значение может меняться
let end = 165; // Значение может меняться
let marked = 58; // Значение может меняться

$('.line').css('top', marked);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поправьте если я некорректно сформулировал вопрос

Comment: @Sevastopol', Здесь скорее всего задача кто математику знает, нужно составить формулу чтобы получить пиксели

Comment: @Sevastopol', start 20 это 0px, end 165 это 150px в блоке, нужно просто как то соотнести числа в пиксели и найти сколько пикселей будет marked

Comment: @Sevastopol', решил вопрос

Comment: @Sevastopol', да, наверное у меня неправильно, я здесь нашел решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155890/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9 только не знаю как все это проверить, буду пробовать разные варианты

Comment: @Sevastopol', наверное мой неверный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let start = 20; // Значение может меняться
let end = 165; // Значение может меняться
let marked = 58; // Значение может меняться

let height = $('.container').height();
let bottom = height * (marked - start) / (end - start);

console.log(bottom +'px');

$('.line').css('bottom', bottom +'px');
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понимаю задачу. Тем не менее, постараюсь как-то вникнуть и что-то сообразить. Всё это решение ниже - "как есть насколько я понимаю задачу"

> start 20 это 0px, end 165 это 150px в блоке, нужно просто как то
> соотнести числа в пиксели и найти сколько пикселей будет marked

Если `start 20 это 0px`, а `end 165 это 150px`, то:

1. Найдем разницу значений: 165-20

```js
let start = 20;
let end = 165;

let rz = end - start
console.log('Разница значений:', rz);
```

2. Узнаем высоту родительского элемента `container`

```js
let h = document.querySelector('.container').scrollHeight;
console.log('Высота контейнера:', h, 'px');
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

3. Узнаем, сколько в одном значении пикселей `px`

```js
let start = 20;
let end = 165;

let rz = end - start
console.log('Разница значений:', rz);

let zpx = 150 / rz // (h / rz)
console.log('В одном значении кол-во px:', zpx);
```

Теперь, зная сколько в одном значении пикселей `px` и зная значение `marked`, мы можем вывести значение для свойства `top` элементу `.line`

```js
let line = document.querySelector('.line') // Элемент, для которого находим значение для свойства 'top:'

let start = 20; // Значение может меняться
let end = 165; // Значение может меняться
let marked = 58; // Значение может меняться

// Узнаем разницу значений
let rz = end - start
console.log('Разница значений:', rz);

// Узнаем количество пикселей в одном значении
let zpx = 150 / rz
console.log('В одном значении кол-во px:', zpx);

// Найдем значение для свойство 'top:' для элемента `.line`
let linepx = marked * zpx
console.log('Кол-во px у marked:', linepx);

// Подставим это значение
line.style.top = linepx + 'px';
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

А теперь это всё сократим и выведем формулу:

```js
let start = 20; // Значение может меняться
let end = 165; // Значение может меняться
let marked = 58; // Значение может меняться
let h = document.querySelector('.container').scrollHeight; // Высота контейнера

// Выведем значение для свойства 'top' по формуле
document.querySelector('.line').style.top = marked * (h / (end - start)) + 'px';
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```